# jquery function only to run on parent of the element clicked

Tags: jquery

I have jquery function that clones divs and increments ID's like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- stuff that needs to be cloned-->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="button" class="cloneRow" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and simple jquery like:

```
var uniqueId = 1;
$(function() {
     $('.cloneRow').click(function() {
        ...
         uniqueId++;  
     });
});
```

This works great if there is only 1 parent div... If i want to create additional section that need their children cloned, like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- stuff that needs to be cloned-->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="button" class="cloneRow" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- stuff that needs to be cloned-->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="button" class="cloneRow" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- stuff that needs to be cloned-->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="button" class="cloneRow" />
    </div>
</div>
```

everything goes crazy, each parent element gets multiple cloned children...
How i can limit click function so it only works in the element where the click button is located?

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the relevant part of the JS, but from the description it sounds like you're appending to all `.row` elements instead of the one related to the button which was clicked. To fix this you can use DOM traversal methods, such as `closest()` and `prev()` to find the elements you need and append to them. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.cloneRow').click(function() {
    var $buttonRow = $(this).closest('.row');
    $buttonRow.prev('.row').clone().insertBefore($buttonRow);
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">Content</div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="cloneRow">Clone</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">Content</div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="cloneRow">Clone</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that generating incremental `id` attributes at runtime, as implied in your code, is an anti-pattern. Don't do it. A better approach is to use common classes along with DOM traversal to relate elements to each other, as the example above shows.

Comment: hi rory, thanks a bunch for the help! in this case how would i increment class of input element in each div (each div would have separate class on the input element)? And also, how to delete each rows except the first one?

Comment: That's my point; don't. I know I said incremental id, but it goes for classes too. Relate elements to each other through the DOM.

Comment: 'how to delete each rows except the first one?' `$(this).closest('.parent').find('.row:not(:first, :last)').remove()` - where `this` is the 'delete button. I'd suggest using a different class than `row` on the button container to make the whole thing simpler

Comment: i need to have different id's or classes on each input element sadly... current setup works great except the original problem - https://jsfiddle.net/bvty0ez7/